# Is the "Eclipse RCP Application" template the same as "Eclipse 4 RCP Application"?

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I'm following this [Vogella tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#generatetemplatewithcontent). It's the first under "Getting Started Guides". The wizard, in part 3.1 pic 4, shows the template chosen is `Eclipse 4 RCP Application`. I don't see this template following the previous steps for the wizard.
I have found the template `Eclipse RCP Application` by changing the option to yes for `Create a rich client application?`. Notice the 4 is missing. I am assuming this is the template I should use because it has the same and only extension `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products`. Also, I see other templates named similar to the others in pic 4 of the wizard. Is this the same template for the tutorial or not and the 4 is missing for a reason?

Comment: I see exactly the templates that are shown in the tutorial. The templates have been around for a couple of years.

Comment: @howlger I'm seeing "Eclipse RCP Application" rather than "Eclipse 4 RCP Application" as well - it seems to create a e4 RCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @greg-449. Using Eclipse 2022-09 for RCP and RAP, while following the tutorial, the 4 is missing. In Neon 3 the number 4 is in the template name. Reminder, the template was found by answering yes under Rich Client Application option (Part 3.1 - pic 3). The 4 is just missing. The template is the same other than the name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).